# Cookie JSP and Servlet Authentication Difficult

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, cookies, session-cookies

I'm creating a simple web system using jsp and servlets. To authenticate my user and check if he/she is logged in, I decide to use cookie, 'cause I think it was simpler.

So I code a servlet to authenticate and save cookie information. Follow code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/xml");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    User user = new User();
    user.setLoginEmail(request.getParameter("login"));
    user.setPsswd(request.getParameter("psswd"));

    UserDAO dao = new UserDAO();

    try {
        user = dao.userAuthentication(user);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    if (user != null) {

        Cookie login = new Cookie("login", user.getLoginEmail());
        Cookie firstName = new Cookie("firstName", user.getUsername().split(" ")[0]);
        Cookie lastName = new Cookie("lastName", user.getUsername().split(" ")[user.getUsername().split(" ").length - 1]);

        login.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24);
        firstName.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24);
        lastName.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24);

        response.addCookie(login);
        response.addCookie(firstName);
        response.addCookie(lastName);

        writer.println("<authentication>done</authentication>");
    } else {
        writer.println("<authentication>fail</authentication>");
    }

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

}
```

Than I made a refresh on current page to capture the cookie and display the logged user on page, but when I check the cookies array is empty. Follow code:

```
<%
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
String name = new String();
String login =  new String();
String authenticated = new String();

for (Cookie c : cookies) {
    if(c.getName().equals("login")){
            name = c.getValue().split("|")[0];
        login = c.getValue().split("|")[1];
        authenticated = c.getValue().split("|")[2];
    }else{
        authenticated = "NAO";
    }
}
%>

<div id="principal">
<div id="login">
    <%
        if(authenticated.equals("SIM")){
            out.println("<p>");
            out.println("Welcome, <b>" + name + "</b> | <a href=\"#\" id=\"logout-link\">log out</a>");
            out.println("</p>");
        }else{
            out.println("<p>");
            out.println("<a href=\"#\" id=\"signin-link\">sign in</a> or <a id=\"create-account\" href=\"create-account.jsp\">create account</a>");
            out.println("</p>");
        }
    %>
</div>
```

JS of the same page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#signin-form").dialog({
            autoOpen : false,
            height : 235,
            width : 350,
            modal : true,
            buttons : {
                "Sign In" : function() {
                    signin();
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel : function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            close : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            show : {
                effect : "slide",
                duration : 300
            },
            hide : {
                effect : "slide",
                duration : 300
            }
        });

        $("#signin-link").click(function() {
            $("#signin-form").dialog("open");
        });
    });

    function signin() {
        $.post("signin", {
            login : $("#txtLoginForm").val(),
            psswd : $("#txtPsswdForm").val()
        }, function(xml) {
            if ($("authentication", xml).text() == "done") {
                location.reload();
            } else {
                alert("Nao Logou!");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Can anyone please help me!?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is fundamentally insecure. You are relying solely on client data to determine the authenticated identity of the user. Spoofing a different authenticated user name would be trivial.

I strongly recommend that you use the built-in authentication mechanisms provided by Servlet containers or use a framework such as Spring Security to do your authentication and authorisation.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your tip. I don't know if it was the best solution, but I solve using HttpSession.